# How to set up SAML with Keycloak and SuiteCRM

Tags: saml, keycloak, suitecrm

I'm setting up SSO with SuiteCRM and Keycloak. I have the URL's mapped but I can't find anywhere on the web that explains how to import the adapter settings into SuiteCRM. I've added the x509 certificate and the login URL redirect works when accessing SuiteCRM. However, the following error is returned when redirected to Keycloak for login:

We're sorry...
Unknown login requester

The Keycloak logs show this:

```
18:54:06,532 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-28) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=demo, clientId=https://suitecrm.mydomain.com/index.php?action=Login&module=Users, userId=null, ipAddress=10.4.20.155, error=client_not_found
```

This is a test environment and the actual URL for the SuiteCRM is 'https://dev.mydomain.com'. The site was copied from 'https://suitecrm.mydomain.com'.

Any help in locating adequate documentation will be appreciated!